# how can i automate a dropdown which opens a text box on selecting a particular value from dropdown using Selenium

Tags: selenium, automation

I have following code -

```
     WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='DRPDWNcasTyp']")); 
     Select select = new Select(dropdown); 
     java.util.List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions(); 
     for(WebElement item:options) 
     { 

         System.out.println("Dropdown values are "+ item.getText());
         if(item.getText().equals("Others"))
         {                                     
              WebElement otherct = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='otherCaseType']")); 
              otherct.click();             
              otherct.sendKeys("Delhi Judiciary board"); 
         }
     }
```

This is not working. After selecting value `"Others"`, textbox should appear & it should accept input. Code inside `if` condition is not working.

`Html` code is given below:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Case Type must be a number." data-val-required="This field can not be empty." id="DRPDWNcasTyp" name="caseTypeID" class="valid">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
```

Comment: provide html properly.

Answer (score 0):

If selecting 'Others' option shows up textbox then you may try the code snippet:

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
        WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='DRPDWNcasTyp']")); 
        Select select = new Select(dropdown); 

        select.selectByVisibleText("Others");

        WebElement otherct = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='otherCaseType']"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(otherct)); //wait until desired textbox appears upto 120 seconds
        otherct.sendKeys("Your desired text");
```